# Getting number appended to the URN from the URI in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider an URL

```
http://localhost:81/proj/friend_profile/1
https://somedomain.in/proj/friend_profile/2
```

Since the URL is not appended with `?id=1` after the friend_profile in the URN.

I will not have the option to get from `$_GET['id'];` from the server-side script

The expected result should print in the console as 1 or 2 from the above set of URL

I'm looking for any of the jQuery or JavaScript to accomplish the same for getting the number appended to the URN from the URI in JavaScript or jQuery

Answer (score 1):

```js
var url = "http://localhost:81/proj/friend_profile/1";
var getNumber = url.toString().split('/').pop();
console.log(getNumber)
```

Note:- If we are getting appended number last then we can split it and Get It.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` and `pop` to get last value of URL.

```js
let  url = 'http://localhost:81/proj/friend_profile/1'
let id = url.split("/").pop(-1);
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

> you should try this

```js
let  url = 'http://localhost:81/proj/friend_profile/1'
let urlArray = url.split("/");
console.log(urlArray[urlArray.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let  url = 'http://localhost:81/proj/friend_profile/1'
let id = url.split("/").pop(999999999999999999);
console.log(id);
```

Comment: hi, please could you provide an explanation of your code for the benefit of future readers? thank you!